# Prevent non-global import

Tags: python, python-import

Non-global imports seem to me mostly used as a workaround for import cycles.
I would like to prevent these "secondary" import cycles though, too.

Is there a tool for "preventing" non-global imports in Python code?

So sufficient if there is a executable, which detects a non-global import and fails.
Not sufficient if I have to change my Python code first!

Comment: No such tool exists, you might be able to use the `ast` module to cook something up to analyse the source code, or even `re` for something quick and dirty (you may be able to get away with looking for something like `\s+global`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a linter, for example https://www.pylint.org/

which will output `a.py:2:4: C0415: Import outside toplevel (json) (import-outside-toplevel)`

For this code

```
def a():
    import json
    print('hello')
```